# How to handel empty elements during doing sum of elements using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<LIST_R7P1_1>
 <R7P1_1> 
 <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV /> 
  <EXP_AFT_CONV >34<EXP_AFT_CONV />
  <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT /> 
  <CREDIT_DER /> 
 </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>


<total><xsl:value-of select="LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV + LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/EXP_AFT_CONV + LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/GUARANTEE_AMOUNT + LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/CREDIT_DER"/></total>
```

In total i am getting null value because of the empty elements like `<CREDIT_DER />, <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV />`  etc .

How to handle that so that I can get a Numeric value

Please suggest

Answer (score 9):

Here is a small example where the trick in the answer of @DevNull will not help:

```
<a>
 <b>5</b>
 <c>
  <d></d>
  <e>1</e>
  <f>2</f>
 </c>
</a>
```

**We want**: `/a/c/d  +  /a/c/f`

**To guarantee that we get the sum, although some of these may be empty or not numbers, use**:

```
sum((/a/c/d|/a/c/f)[number(.) = number(.)])
```

**Explanation**:

The XPath expression: `(/a/c/d|/a/c/f)[number(.) = number(.)]`

selects only those of all united nodes, whose value is a number. Therefore, the `sum()` function will be provided only with numeric arguments and will not produce `NaN`.

The expression `number(.) = number(.)` is true only when `.` is a number.

Here we use that `number(somethingNon-Number)` is `NaN`

and that `NaN` isn't equal to anything, even to `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<total><xsl:value-of select="sum(/LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/*/text())"/></total>
```

You also need to fix your XML (the `EXP_AFT_CONV` end tag):

```
<LIST_R7P1_1>
  <R7P1_1>
    <ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV/>
    <EXP_AFT_CONV>34</EXP_AFT_CONV>
    <GUARANTEE_AMOUNT/>
    <CREDIT_DER/>
  </R7P1_1>
</LIST_R7P1_1>
```

Comment: This technique is not applicable in the case when the nodes to sum are not all the text descendents of some element. See my answer for a solution that works in all cases.

Comment: @Dimitre: Very true. My answer was specific to the example.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Here you select a singleton node set, then `fn:sum` cast this node with `fn:number` to get the sum. But the OP explicity ask for `LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/ORIG_EXP_PRE_CONV + LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/EXP_AFT_CONV + LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/GUARANTEE_AMOUNT + LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/CREDIT_DER`. So, other expresion besides Dimitre's one, would be `sum(LIST_R7P1_1/R7P1_1/*/text())`